# bootstrap grid gets broken

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So here is the [removed link](https://herokuapp.com)
It is in russian but it doesn't matter.
The thing is that bootstrap grid sometimes gets broken and I don't know why. Some times it looks normal but then I zoom page to 75% and it brokes.
I gueess it also brokes on different laptops screens without zooming.
Should I provide you some code or something else?
[image]

Comment: Giving your items inside each column a min height will fix your broken grid.

Comment: Please post your code to create a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `height: 150px;` to ur `.category-wrap` to fix it.

```
.category-wrap {
    margin-top: 15px;
    height: 150px;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can add a CSS clear "reset" every 4 items like this. This will work without setting a specific height.

```
@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .category-wrap:nth-child(4n+1) {
        clear: left;
    }
}
```

http://codeply.com/go/ubs5zGee5g